# Where should I download CorFlags.exe from?

Tags: .net, sdk, corflags

I'm running Windows Server 2008 64-bit "workstation" and would like to get [corflags.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). Which SDK do I need to download?

I know about [.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=1AEF6FCE-6E06-4B66-AFE4-9AAD3C835D3D&displaylang=en#Overview) and [Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=F26B1AA4-741A-433A-9BE5-FA919850BDBF&displaylang=en) but I was hoping to find something smaller as these are quite large downloads.

Also the note about 2.0 SDK seems to suggest to download the 3.5 one, should I follow that?

Comment: So many great answers, yet none with a convenient, bloat-free download of just the EXE like you asked for!  I came across **[CorFlags.exe](http://everything-virtual.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/corflags.exe)** hosted by the helpful gentleman at [Everything-Virtual](http://www.everything-virtual.com/?p=279).

As of 2012-Sep-27 it passed VirusTotal with no warnings and the EXE did the trick for me right out of the box.

Comment: @rkagerer the links seems not working now.

Comment: @arvindwill the link works, but it's corflags 64bit

Answer (score 13):

The current official version is in the "[Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en)". (Requires XP or later.)

You just need to install the .NET Development Tools subcomponent (Developer Tools -> Windows Development Tools -> .NET Development Tools).

That should place corflags.exe in Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.1\Bin

Comment: There's now a version of the SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1

Answer (score 6):

If you install the .NET framework (you should already have it), it'll be at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0\Bin\corflags.exe

Come to think of it, you may need to install 
the Microsoft .NET 2.0 SDK from *[.NET Framework 2.0 Software Development Kit (SDK) (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=1AEF6FCE-6E06-4B66-AFE4-9AAD3C835D3D&displaylang=en)* -- check for that file first.

Comment: Yep I know about this download but I was hoping to find something smaller... also, a note under the overview suggests to download another one which is even bigger at 1.3G...

Comment: Yea, I just noticed the site.  Hell, want me to just email you the file?  If that's all you want from the SDK (since the compilers and such are in the framework)

Comment: Heh. Sure, email id good. my stackoverflow user name at gmail,

Comment: Hmm, in C:\Program Files\Microsoft.NET\SDK\v2.0 64bit\Bin for me.  But your post did help me find it so you get a vote. Thanks.

Comment: hey, could you email that to me too please, my stackoverflow username at gmail as well.

Comment: For the purpose of SO and the good of humanity (*for science*), why don't you just put the file in a share and link to it.

Answer (score 6):

As rakslice already pointed out, there is now the 'SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1' available as the latest version at *[Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=c17ba869-9671-4330-a63e-1fd44e0e2505&displaylang=en)*.

This can also be run under Windows XP and later and still contains corflags.exe.

Note that if one is purely interested in the `coreflags.exe`, one chooses to only install the '.NET Development Tools' subcomponent, about 75 MB will be thrown on the harddisk.
After doing so, I found the desired tool at `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0\Bin\CorFlags.exe`.

Answer (score 0):

See *[Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en)*. The .NET SDK has been bundled with the Windows SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version is 10.1.

Either download and install from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/bb980924.aspx,

or, as I did, use chocolatey (https://chocolatey.org/install):

```
choco install windows-sdk-10.1
```

The 32bit `CorFlags.exe` file is in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools`,

the 64bit version in

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64`.